# Subscribing to templated message type

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a templated class that accepts a message type as a parameter and a topic as an argument. I define the subscriber in the constructor:

```
    subscriber = n.subscribe(sub_topic, 1000, &TemplatedClass::callbackFunction, this);
```

and the callback function is defined as:

```
template<class T>
void TemplatedClass<T>::callbackFunction(const typename T::ConstPtr& incoming_msg) 
{
     ...
}
```

But the callback function is never called. When I subscribe to the topic from `main` using a subscriber that isn't from a templated class, the callback function is called, so the topic is being published to. I considered that it could be that the signature `const typename ...` might be causing issues, but of course the program won't compile without `typename`. Any ideas?

---

Turns out the issue was that I'd instantiated two subscribers in my constructor, but forgot to adjust the name of the second one. I had:

```
    subscriber1 = n.subscribe(sub_topic1, 1000, &TemplatedClass::callbackFunction1, this);
    subscriber1 = n.subscribe(sub_topic2, 1000, &TemplatedClass::callbackFunction2, this);
```

so `subscriber1` was being overwritten and `subscriber2` was never defined. My code was otherwise right, so I'm leaving it here in case anybody else needs the syntax for subscribers in templated classes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225727/subscribing-to-templated-message-type/) by [djsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/25492/djsw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2016-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use rostopic or rqt_graph to introspect and make sure that your subscriber is actually subscribed to the right topic, and have a look at the publisher and subscriber logs to make sure that there isn't a topic type mismatch.

Also note that the subscriber only exists for as long as the `subscriber` object exists; if the `subscriber` object goes out of scope and is destructed, it unsubscribes from that topic.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/25492/djsw/) on 2016-02-03**:
It's not a scope issue - the class subscribes to two topics: one subscriber is `const typename T::ConstPtr&` and one is `const std_msgs::Empty::ConstPtr&`, and the second subscriber does exist. I checked with `rqt_graph` and `rostopic info` and the first subscriber does not exist.

**Comment by [djsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/25492/djsw/) on 2016-02-03**:
Turns out it was a silly mistake. Thanks for the answer.